# Using StringBuffer and StringBuilder as a method return type in Java

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder, return-type, stringbuffer

Is it a bad idea to use StringBuilder or StringBuffer as a method's return type in a Java ? I have often returned String as a return type from a Java method but never StringBuilder or StringBuffer even I have done operations using them inside a method.

Could anyone please educate me if it is recommended NOT to use StringBuilder and StringBuffer as method return type ? If not, what are the reasons for it ? One reason could be that these two are mutable. But how does it make any difference since we often use other Derived Type as a method return type which are mutable.

Could someone please explain the demerits (if any) of using StringBuffer and Builder as method return type with a code ,maybe?

Comment: Mutability is one concern, unless of course you want to allow the caller to make further changes.  In my travels, most of the time the point of using `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder` is to output a `String` at some point.

Comment: all doubt clear check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834479/string-or-stringbuilder-return-values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StringBuffer` is old and was substituted by `StringBuilder` for speed.

*Returning* a StringBuilder could be bad style: sometimes it is better to pass a StringBuilder as *parameter*. Compare:

*[best] As parameter:*

```
void dump(StringBuilder sb) {
    sb.append(name);
    for (Foo child : children) {
        child.dump(sb);
    }
}
```

*[unproblematic, inefficient] Comparison with immutable value aggregated:*

```
String toString() {
    return name + left.toString() + right.toString();
}
```

*[ugly] Comparison with returning a mutable value:*

```
StringBuilder dump() {
    StringBulder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (Foo child : children) {
        sb.append(child.dump()); // Inefficient
    }
    return sb;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea of the builder pattern is to separate construction from representation.

It is absolutely fine if you use the return value to continue the process of constructing an object. On the other hand, it is bad if the return value won't be modified and is already used as a representation.

There is nothing specific regarding these classes, they just represent a mutable sequence of characters. One thing you need to do is to draw a line between construction and representation.